# How to run selenium on a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: firefox, debian, raspberry-pi, chromium, selenium

I've been looking everywhere but I can't figure out how to run selenium on a raspberry pi.

I've tried to install `iceweasel` but there is not package found when I try to install. Tried to run selenium with `firefox-esr` but it crashes. Tried with `chromium` but it just errors out.

I'm very confused on how to get selenium to run on raspberry pi. Can anyone tell me? All the other solutions are outdated and don't work.